# iOS SDK iOS9 - User Gets Logged Out every time

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I've an app which was working fine earlier but when tested on iOS9, I am seeing that the users are getting logged out and being forced to login when they launch the app. This is very annoying for customers.

I tried to debug it and I am able to trace the flow back to `SFUserAccountManager.m` but not sure what is causing it.

Is this a known bug? Or has anything changed in mobile SDK that I need to configure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been a known issue with iOS9 but the good thing is that it's already fixed in 3.3.1 release. The root cause is that `TheunarchiveObjectWithFile: message` of the `NSKeyedUnarchiver` class now returns `nil` upon failure, instead of throwing an exception.

Either update your Mobile SDK to 3.3.1 or update `SFUserAccountManager.m` from this [pull request](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/pull/1123/files).